# Google has disabled use of the maps api for this application. See the terms of service for more information

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using google maps API in javascript for last 2 weeks. But since yesterday, it always shows an error, when I run my app. I'm enclosing the picture of error bellow. I know there is a lot of questions like this on forums etc. but that solutions don't work properly and I am new at programming with Google Maps.

I couldn't embed picture directly (because I don't have enough reputations yet), so I'm enclosing link to the snap-screen error alert:
(http://shrani.si/f/1A/je/1zlpIdXs/zajeta-slika.jpg)

My javascript code to access to the Maps is:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=false"</script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: remove API_KEY on link :3.

**http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false**

Comment: Your application obviously violates the Terms of service(the URL in the alert isn't just for fun). Follow the terms, that is all you may get as an answer based on the given information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think API keys don't work because of affair of fake Google Certificates. Here is full-detailed article: 
Theregister.co.uk[1](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/07/09/google_warns_of_dodgy_digital_certificates_coming_from_indian_authorities/)